# How to use WPF UserControls or Windows from inside Visual FoxPro 9

Tags: wpf, visual-foxpro

I have a very, very large and complex Visual FoxPro 9 application.  I'd like to rewrite portions of this application in WPF with the ultimate goal of completing cutting over a couple of years from now.  I've spent a considerable amount of time searching google and stackoverflow for an end to end "hello world" type sample of how to implement this with COM interop.  Found bits and pieces but nothing complete that shows both the FoxPro side and the WPF side.

My gut tells me I'm likely to run into issues with XAML resources, third party controls, or other normal functionalities of a WPF app if I try to run it via COM Interop.

So, two questions.  Can anyone point me to an small end to end sample that either launches WPF windows from FoxPro or lets me drop WPF user controls on a FoxPro form?  Or am I right with my concerns of potential interop issues and should avoid this altogether?  If so, is there a recommended way for these two executables to communicate with each other?

Comment: in couple of years, windows 7 will be deprecated and WPF with it. You should look at some newer stuff, maybe Electron or UWP if you don't have problem with windows

Comment: Is there a recent resource from Microsoft that states this or is this just your opinion?

Comment: It is a very very large and complex problem. I did exactly what you are asking. Here some resource: https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/VfpDotNetInterop/DotNetFromVFP.asp ; http://www.codemag.com/Article/0703112 ; https://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetfromVfp/DotNetFromVfp_ComplexObjects.asp ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186829/is-it-possible-to-package-wpf-window-as-com-object . I can also tell you that i had problems using WPF class Application. If you have patience i can write you my case of study.

Comment: I do not have a comment on WPF's future. But anyways, it is a MS specific thing. After VFP, would you still risk yourself again trusting MS? That is one thing, the other is, I would keep away from COM (yet another platform specific thing). I am in the same position as you do and did some of what you describe in the past and will never go that route again (COM and Silverlight namely - SL yet another sample showcasing MS trustability). Maybe you should look forward to using REST, micro, gRPC ... services for data and HTML based interfaces for UI (Qt is another nice cross platform UI option)

Comment: I have to stick with technology that can integrate as closely as possible to the foxpro application.  It would take close to $500k in development costs to rewrite it in its entirety and ownership just isn't going to do that.  Doing it a little at a time is my best option for now and that leaves WPF.  Found some code samples for launching processes and monitoring whether they are still running.  So, I'll probably just go with some sort of dual process implementation and enable the foxpro and wpf apps to communicate.

Comment: @RobDog why you think that WPF will be deprecated? it's running well on W10.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea whether you can run wpf inside visual FoxPro. I would guess you'd have to write it as an activex.
I recently did some work extending a MS Access app.
My wpf app is completely separate and runs alongside the ms access app.
I communicated between the two using MS Message Queue - which is a com component.
Maybe this sort of approach could work for you.

When I wanted to show a screen in wpf from access I added a piece of xml to the local message queue.
The wpf app listens for these messages, casts them to objects which tells it which screen to show and gives it any parameters.
MS Access subscribes to the received message event on the message queue and that way it can tell when the wpf window closes and the user is done.
This was intended to use the strangler pattern to gradually replace functionality in the old access app.

Here's some code for the queuelistener that drives everything. The various pop classes are deserialised from the message and I build that as a string in access.

```
internal class QueueListener
{
    public const string qFromMadge = @".\private$\XXXXQ";
    public static string qToMadge = @".\private$\XXXXReturnQ";
    private MessageQueue mq;
    internal QueueListener()
    {
        try
        {
            SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
            SubscribeHandler();

            var mqSend = setUpQueue(qToMadge);
            mqSend.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
    private MessageQueue setUpQueue(string qName)
    {
        MessageQueue q;
        if (MessageQueue.Exists(qName))
        {
            q = new MessageQueue(qName);
        }
        else
        {
            q = MessageQueue.Create(qName);
        }
        q.ResetPermissions();
        q.SetPermissions("Everyone", MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlEntryType.Set);
        q.Purge();
        return q;
    }
    private void ReceiveMsgCompleted(Object source, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
    {
        MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)source;
        Message m = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);
        m.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { "XXXX.Popaaaa, XXXX"
                                                    , "XXXX.Popbbbb, XXXXX"
                                                    , "XXXX.Popcccc, XXXX"
                                                    , "XXXX.Popdddd, XXXX"
        });

        ((BasePopView) m.Body).Pop();

        mq.BeginReceive();
    }

    public  void UnsubscribeHandler()
    {
        if (mq == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        mq.Close();
        mq.ReceiveCompleted -= new ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(ReceiveMsgCompleted);
        mq = null;
    }
    public  void SubscribeHandler()
    {
        if(mq != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        mq = setUpQueue(qFromMadge);
        mq.ReceiveCompleted += ReceiveMsgCompleted;
        mq.BeginReceive();
    }
```

Comment: Interesting topic about using XAML in VFP. https://www.sweetpotatosoftware.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/11/xaml-in-visual-foxpro/ -- yes, it was done by place WPF control inside Windows Form control and after that all to ActiveX component